# Generator by reference

Tags: generator, php-7.1

I am testing generator by reference of two ways:

**N°1:** It works

```
<?php

$value = 3;

function &gen_reference() {
    global $value;

    while ($value > 0) {
        yield $value;
    }
}

foreach (gen_reference() as &$number) {
    --$number;
}

echo($value . PHP_EOL); // 0
```

**N°2:** It not display than I want.

```
<?php

class Test
{

    public $data = [];

    function __construct($data){
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    function &getIterator() {
        foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
            yield $key => $value;
        }
    }

    function printData()
    {
        foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
            echo($key . ':' . $value . PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
}

$data = array('one'=>'Curly', 'two'=>'Larry', 'three'=>'Moe');
$t = new Test($data);

foreach ($t->getIterator() as $key => &$value) {
    $value = strtoupper($value); // Does not update $this->data
}

$t->printData();
```

Display:

```
one:Curly
two:Larry
three:Moe
```

I expected:

```
one:CURLY
two:LARRY
three:MOE
```

Any correction or suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Add & to $value in &getIterator function for keep to reference:

```
function &getIterator() {
    foreach ($this->data as $key => &$value) { // Here add & to $value
        yield $key => $value;
    }
}
```

**Code complete:**

```
class Test
{

    public $data = [];

    function __construct($data){
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    function &getIterator() {
        foreach ($this->data as $key => &$value) { // Here add & to $value
            yield $key => $value;
        }
    }

    function printData()
    {
        foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
            echo($key . ':' . $value . PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
}

$data = array('one'=>'Curly', 'two'=>'Larry', 'three'=>'Moe');
$t = new Test($data);

foreach ($t->getIterator() as $key => &$value) {
    $value = strtoupper($value); // Does not update $this->data
}

$t->printData();
```